# What is non-concatenation axis in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am appending a dataframe df1 to a dataframe df2 with both having the same columns but not necessarily in the same order.

```
df = df1.append(df2)
```

I am seeing this warning as a result of the above operation.

"FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default."

I understand that the resulting dataframe has columns in alphabetical order after this operation but I am trying to underrstand the definition of non-concatenation axis which is mentioned in the warning. What is it and where is it significant in pandas?

Comment: If you share a small data of what you have it is easier to explain what is "wrong" with **your** data. Preferably this should be a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the other axis—the axis along which you do not concatenate. If you're concatenating along the index (axis=0), then the non-concatenation axis would be 1 (i.e., the columns), and vice versa.